# Login via email + set_own_login_name + pas.plugins.sqlalchemy = change address fail

Tags: sqlalchemy, plone

I'm using pas.plugins.sqlalchemy on a fresh new Plone 4.1 installation.
I set Plone to have the email address as login name.

It's all ok, but If I want to change the email address via personal-information panel I obtain an error:
You are not a Plone member. You are probably registered on the root user folder. Please notify an administrator if this is unexpected.

In case I would change another personal data field I don't obtain errors.

The problem seems to be the set_own_login_name function of Products.CMFPlone (utils.py).
Details here http://pastie.org/3780218

Thank's 
Vito

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as an admin user defined in the Zope root?

If that is the case, then see if you can change the login name by going to the acl_users in the Zope root and changing it there.

Otherwise, temporarily switch off emaillogin, change your email, and switch emaillogin back on.

Note that there is a comment (by me) in the utils.py code right before this KeyError is raised, which points to a possible solution that I don't really like:

```
# PLIP9214: For a user in the zope root we could do something like this:
# userfolder = member.getUser().__parent__.users
# userfolder.updateUser(member.id, loginname)
# But it is probably best not to touch root zope users.
```

Comment: Hi maurits, i was a simple user (with the auth via pas sql).

Comment: What the emaillogin code tries to do here, is change your login name. For this it gets all IUserManagement plugins, calls `userfolder.updateUser(member.id, loginname)` on each one until it has found a plugin where this succeeds. I guess either the pas sql plugin is not registered as IUserManagement plugin, or the call fails for some unknown reason.  If you are comfortable with the python debugger, I would suggest you add a pdb.set_trace() in this set_own_login_name function and see if you can get more info from there.

Comment: Solved. Pas.Plugins.SqlAlchemy miss the "updateUser" method. I'll try to patch and notify to the plugin's dev team